# Delphi DBGrid set column width and scolling effect

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, dbgrid, tdbgrid

I have my DBgrid connected via TDataSource and Firedac TFDQuery.
Data is populated from query. Headers are the fields returned by the query.

I want to make 1st and 5th column non resizable and other fields as resizable.
How Do I fix column width only for two columns of DBGrid?

And on other form, I have Tclientdataset connected to DBGrid.
When I do clientdataset.next and it goes through all records, DBGrid automatically scrolls till the end and gives flickering effect.

Comment: First part of the question is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509924/adjust-column-width-dbgrid

Answer (score 1):

For the second question use the `DisableControls` and `EnableControls` methods of the TDataSet descendant your using (TFDQuery in this case) if you want to do things without the controls being updated.